# linux find files with optional character in their name

Tags: regex, linux, find

suppose I have two files: `ac` and `abc`. I want to find a regex to match both files. Normally I would expect the following regex to work, but it never does:

```
find ./ -name ab?c
```

I have tried escaping or not the questionmark, this never seems to work. Normally in the regex documentations I have found; `?` means: *previous character repeated 0 or 1 times*, but `find` doesn't seem to understand this.

I have tried this on two different find versions: GNU find version 4.2.31 and 
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0

PS: this works with `*`, but I specifically would like to match just **one optional character**.

```
find ./ -name a*c
```

gives

```
./ac
./abc
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression passed to `-name` is not a regex, it is a glob expression. A (single) glob expression can't be used for your use case but you can use regular expressions using `-regex`:

```
find -regex '.*/ab?c'
```

Btw, the default regular expression language is Emacs Style as explained here : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression . You can change the regex language using `-regextype`.

Answer (score 6):

To match the expression with **only one optional character** try using `or` option:

```
touch abc ac abbc
find . -name "a?c" -or -name "ac"
```

Gives you only: `abc` and `ac` names.

Generally you can build pretty complex find queries using `or` and `and` options =)

Answer (score 3):

The find `-name` option uses a glob pattern, which is not the same as a regex. For globs, `?` means any single character. If you want a character to be optional, you need to use two patterns:

```
find ./ -name abc -o -name ac
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good enough to have a solution but knowing `find`'s `-regex` option matches on whole entry is essential. So you can't just do a partial match:

```
-regex 'ab?c'
```

You have to use one or two dot-stars:

```
-regex '.*ab?c.*'
```

Also without wildcards this would be possible using `grep`:

```
ls . | grep 'ab\?c'
```